# Paste an array of unknown size to a location on a workbook (VBA)

Tags: arrays, vba

I have a function that creates dynamic arrays based on the content of different sheets- each array is of a different size. I would like to paste the contents of each array into the worksheet on which the function was called. Given that each array is of different size, it seems I cannot use the transpose function. Any suggestions?

Here is the function that creates the arrays:

```
Function FindConstituents(ByRef ys As Worksheet) As String()
Dim a() As String
Dim size As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

size = 0
Dim row As Integer
row = 2
ReDim Preserve a(size)
While ys.Cells(row, 4) <> ""
    If IsInTable(ys.Cells(row, 4), ys, 2) Then
    ReDim Preserve a(size)
    a(size) = ys.Cells(row, 4)
    size = size + 1
    End If
    row = row + 1
Wend
size = size + 1

<<Code to paste contents of a() onto a place in the worksheet>>

FindConstituents = a
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use Resize, something like to get the results in one column:

```
ys.Range("G1").Resize(Ubound(a)+1).Value = Application.Transpose(a)
```

If you do not want to use Transpose then you will need to iterate through a.

```
Dim i as long
For i = Lbound(a) to Ubound(a)
    ys.Range("G1").Offset(i).Value = a(i)
Next i
```

---

Edit just realized you probably are calling this from the worksheet.  This will need to be called from a sub that does the pasting back to the sheet a function called by a worksheet cannot affect the values of other cells.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Suppose I wanted to begin listing the values in the same row, but change columns: G1,H1, etc., how would you modify the for loop?

Comment: Remove the Transpose on the first and use `Offset(,i)` in the second.

Comment: oh, and on the first you also will need to change `Resize(Ubound(a)+1)` to `Resize(,Ubound(a)+1)`